# how to not exact matching 2 csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dictionary

I have 2 csv file, dictionary.csv and file.csv, i want to check if words in dictionary.csv exists in file.csv. Some rows in dictionary.csv contains more than 2 words, and i wanted to know if there is a way  to do this,

if there are 3 words in the row, and at least 2/3 words from the row matched in file.csv, return 1, else 0

if there are 2 words in the row, and at least 1/2 words from the row matched in file.csv, return 1, else 0

Below are my code so far, it is making exact matching

```
file=pd.read_csv("file.csv")
dictionary=pd.read_csv("dictionary.csv")

pattern='|'.join(dictionary)

news["contain diseases1"] = np.where(
    news["STORY"].str.contains(pattern, na=False),
    1, 0
)

news.to_csv("clues.csv")
```

To further aid your understanding to my question, below are the content of dictionary.csv and file.csv

```
dictionary.csv

sigmoid colon cancer
site specific early onset breast cancer syndrome
skin cancer
```

```
file.csv

id   STORY
0    Ari have a colon cancer
1    Cancer is an epidemic
2    Breast cancer can happen to both genders
```

The output that i should get from these file is

```
clue.csv
id   STORY                                      contain diseases1
0    Ari have a colon cancer                         1
1    Cancer is an epidemic                           1
2    Breast cancer can happen to both genders        1
3    Prioritizing the health of skin                 0
4    A specific camping site is only for early birds 0
```

As of now, since the code i have right now is exact matching, i keep on getting 0

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the fuzzywuzzy python library?  It is a string-matching library open-sourced by SeatGeek.  It provides a matching score based on imperfect matches, and then you decide which threshold is close-enough to be a match.

In my experience, I've used it to match physician names from different data sources (e.g. some say "Dr." some say "M.D.", some first names are contracted, some last names changed due to maiden names).

Here are 2 links to the library.

https://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/

https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy